# Can anyone tell me what does the problem ask?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone tell me what does the problem ask? What is ${g \circ f \circ h}(0)$? Initially, I thought it is $g(0)*f(0)*h(0)$, but the answer is not right.$$$$
[image]

Comment: $g \circ f \circ h$ usually denotes function composition, so you need to figure out $g\left(f\left(h(0)\right)\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $g(0)*f(0)*h(0)$ is incorrect, then the question notation must denote function composition. You find $h(0)$, take that value and input it into $f(x)$, and then take that result and input it into $g(x)$.

Does that make sense?

Try it yourself and check to see if you got what I got. The answer is

> 4